# Why can't VSCode recognize Chinese?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'va already set `"files.autoGuessEncoding": true` in setttings.json.
And altough I manually changed the UTF-8 on the lower right corner of the interface to GB18030 or GBK, it still didn't work.

[image: Chinese characters show as ����]

Comment: Does this help? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in Settings.json would solve this question:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "python": "set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 && python -u",
}
```

[image]

Comment: happy coding :-)